# How do I get the actual geometry attributes of a window created using tkinter and python 3.6.0?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I create a window which is 1500 pixels wide x 900 pixels tall with an x offset of 220 pixels and a y offset of 120 pixels.  Immediately after the creation I try to access the width and height of the window and I get values that don't correspond to the actual window.

This is the printed output.

```
Right after Creation
size_string 1500x900+220+120
current geometry 1x1+220+120
root_width, root_reqwidth 1 200
root_height, root_reqheight 1 200
winfo_x, winfo_y 0 0
```

This is the code.

```
from tkinter import *

def callback():
    print ("Not Yet Defined")

root = Tk()
root.title("Manage My Money")

#  This segment sets the size of the window and the offsets
win_height_pixels=900
win_width_pixels=1500
win_x_offset_pixels=220
win_y_offset_pixels=120
size_string=str(win_width_pixels)+"x"+str(win_height_pixels)+"+"+str(win_x_offset_pixels)+"+"+str(win_y_offset_pixels)
root.geometry(size_string)
#   This prints out the attributes of the window
print("Right after Creation")
print ("size_string",size_string)
current_geom=root.geometry()
print ("current geometry", current_geom)
root_width=root.winfo_width()
root_reqwidth=root.winfo_reqwidth()
print ("root_width, root_reqwidth", root_width, root_reqwidth)
root_height=root.winfo_height()
root_reqheight=root.winfo_reqheight()
print ("root_height, root_reqheight", root_height, root_reqheight)
winfo_x=root.winfo_x()
winfo_y=root.winfo_y()
print("winfo_x, winfo_y", winfo_x, winfo_y)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "values that don't correspond"?

Answer (score 1):

If you call `winfo_width()` or `winfo_reqwidth()` before the window appears on the screen, you will not get the actual size of the window. You must first make the window appear.